# SQL Server Bulk Insert Special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

I am using SQL SERVER 2012.

I am trying to insert below characters in SQL server using Bulk insert command but it convert to some wierd characters.

```
"ố 39 đường 37 phường Bình An, quận 2"

---------
create table #shipaddress
(
    Street1 nvarchar (512)
)

BULK INSERT #shipaddress
FROM 'D:\test.txt'
with (DATAFILETYPE='widechar', FIELDTERMINATOR=',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIRSTROW = 2, CODEPAGE = 'ACP', KEEPNULLS);

select * from #shipaddress
```

---

I have tried many options DataFileType, CodePage but none works. It converts to this kind of string:

```
"á»‘ 39 Ä‘Æ°á»ng 37 phÆ°á»ng BÃ¬nh An, quáº­n 2"
```

Comment: Can you please share table structure and some data example??

Comment: Main issue is like #shipaddress is not populate correctly. My other flow is fine thanks. If you check with above data only 1 value in txt file then you get same issue.